# Gensim text rank:

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, summarization

Below is the code I used to preprocess the text and apply text rank(I followed the gensim textrank tutorial). Please help me with a method to get better results. My text data is a column from a csv with more than 2000 rows. (each row, a sentence).

Output I get is 18 lines (Each different line, not a paragraph) of text as 
summary, and 20 words as keywords. Will the output be a paragraph of text as summary? Can we control the number of keywords to be displayed

```
reg_ex = r'[^a-zA-Z]'
replace = ' '
wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
#stop = stopwords.words('english')

comp_df = df['COMMENT'].str.replace(reg_ex, replace).apply(lambda t: ' '.join([wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w)for w in t.split()])).str.lower()

aa = comp_df.to_string()

import requests

import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

from gensim.summarization import summarize
from gensim.summarization import keywords


print ('Summary:')
print (summarize(aa,ratio=0.01))

print ('\nKeywords:')
print (keywords(aa, ratio=0.01))
```

Answer (score 0):

output can not be a paragraph as summary. Based upon text rank algorithm, it will give you the top rank sentences in your output as a summary. You can increase the output sentences by increasing the ration. Same can be applicable in keywords too.